# Разбить массив на части

Tags: массивы, php

Как разбить на части? В каждой части должно быть $pnum количество элементов. То есть, на выходе должно быть:

```
    Array ( 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 [2] => 9 ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 10) 
)
```

То есть, если элементов в массиве 11, а нужны части по 3 элемента в каждом, то можно, чтобы в последнем было 2 элемента.

$posts - это общий массив, который нужно разбить.

**UPD**::KNES:
Вернул хотя бы часть текста, иначе ответы теряют смысл. :)
Просьба не удалять текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
array_chunk($posts,$pnum,$preserve_keys/*bool*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($posts as $id=>$k) {
 foreach($posts as $id=>$k) {
```

естественно одинаковые, цикл в цикле да еще и одинаковые.